# How to change text based on dropdown2?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have a combobox and i want to change a text based on user selection.

See [this link](http://prntscr.com/g61zj).

I want to change the last word based on *Dropdown* option.
so if the user chooses daily it says days, weekly says weeks,  monthly the word say months

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple example to do it.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.opts = [
        {text : "daily", value : "days"},
        {text : "weekly", value : "weeks"},
        {text : "monthly", value : "months"}
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x.text for x in opts">
</select>

<h1>You selected: {{selectedName.value}}</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: cool i will test it but seems fine.

Also i have a combobox with this two items: after and on

so then when user select after it appears a textboxwith type of text and if user select on it appears to selct a date

eg:

after 10(textbox) occurences 
on (date)